# How to fix error "ruby.exe seems not to be installed" in Windows 7 where both Miktex 2.9 and Ruby have been installed?

Tags: installing, context

I have installed Miktex 2.9 with the latest update. I work with `latex.exe` successfully.

I want to learn ConTeXt and I installed Ruby. To get better settings, I restart my computer.

After restarting, I got the following figure. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Since you are just getting started with ConTeXt, you can ignore MkII (the version that uses pdftex as an engine) and directly try MkIV (the version that uses luatex as an engine). The MkIV wrapper scripts are written in lua and do not require ruby. Simply try 'context filename' to see if it works.

Comment: @Aditya: It does not work. It stops at "!undefined control sequence. 1.2 \usemodule[circuitikz]"

Comment: Did you see cirtuittikz documentation about fixing the tikz bug (tikz does not switch the complete catcodetable) to work with ConTeXt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the environment variable `PATH` to add ruby's installation directory.

Comment: the root directory of ruby or its nested directory?

Comment: @xport: wherever `ruby.exe` is.

Comment: + @Caramdir: thanks. The error vanishes at infinity.