# TexLive cannot find Ruby.exe

Tags: installing, texlive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix error “ruby.exe seems not to be installed” in Windows 7 where both Miktex 2.9 and Ruby have been installed?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8863/how-to-fix-error-ruby-exe-seems-not-to-be-installed-in-windows-7-where-both-mik)

I just installed TexLive 2010 on a computer that already had Ruby installed but get the *`Ruby.exe` not found* message when running `texexec hello`. Is there something I must set?

Comment: If you open a command line in windows and type 'ruby' (without the ' ' of course), do you get a "command can not be found" or similar? If so, you need to add ruby to your environment variables. Also you need to enable write18 as a pdflatex option in order to allow the call of external software

Comment: @Martin: write18 is only useful to execute external programs from pdftex, but here it's quite the contrary: `texexec` is a ruby script which executes pdftex (or xetex). With TeX Live on Windows, it means texexec.exe is a small executable which looks for ruby and invokes it.